# 3 ImageButtons onClick opens same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, imagebutton

I have 3 `ImageButton`'s which should open different activities but it does open same activity every time.

Comment: What size screen are you using? You're button sizes, paired with not specifying a relationship for positioning, would indicate to me maybe that the buttons are over the top of each other, and your onclick is only called on the one on top (number 3 I would think with a quick glance)

Comment: Yes, seems the buttons were over the top of each other. I fixed it by setting layoutOnRightOf . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using

```
BaseTabGroup parentActivity = (BaseTabGroup)getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("Engines", edit);
```

Just use

```
startActivity(intent);
```

See: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Your problem could also be inside the layout though.

Comment: Is not working this way either. I attached the XML. I am using those 2 lines because this activity is part of a TabGroup and I always want to keep the tabs on top.

Comment: Are you sure the buttons aren't overlapping each other? The actual image might not be the actual touch region of the button. Give them a background color or something.